# Is the adapter design pattern for change of input only or change of input and/or output?

Tags: design-patterns

1. If I am correct, the adapter design pattern changes a class or
   function to have a different interface. Does that mean that it
   changes a class or function

   - to accept a different type of input only, or
   - to accept a different type of input, and/or to provide a different type of output?
2. I saw "wrapper" is used to describe a case of changing a 
   function to provide a different type of output.

   Is "wrapper" a design pattern?

   What is the difference a wrapper and an adapter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. An Adapter changes functions to accept different input **and/or** to return different output (i.e. the second bullet). Whether one or both changes are needed depends on how close the *adaptee* interface is to the *target* interface to begin with. If the adaptee already accepts arguments which the target provides or already returns a value which the target accepts, then only half the equation needs adapting.
2. Wrapper is a generic term sometimes used in place of Adapter, but beware! Wrapper is also a synonym for the Decorator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Adapter pattern basically has three players : Adapter class, Client code, Actual logic implementing class.

Adapter class implements the interface accepted by the client`s code. It is composed of the instance of the object of the actual class performing the computation or processing logic. 
To do the processing the actual logic processor class needs some input parameters in a speciifc format and outputs the result as per its implementation.

Client code is independent of these input output format as it is not bound by any means to confirm to any contract with logic processor class.

Adapter adapts the logic processor class so that its logic processing code can be used by the client code. Adapter confirms itself to the interface as needed by the client. This interface **may have** different methods as compared to the methods defined in actual logic processor, each method may have different input number or/and type of parameters and different type of return type as compared to corresponding methods declared by the interface accepted by the client. Adapter will adapt all these different methods, input parameters and out put return type so that client code can use the logic processor class.

Wrapper as mentioned in other answers may be used for adapter but I feel should not as Decorator wraps one object to *enhance* its behavior, Proxy also wraps its underlying service class to provide a *sofisticated or more versatile surrogate* (with additional checks, alternate or additional behavior) , then Adapter too wraps the logic processor class to *adapt* it to the interface acceptable by client code. Moreover adapter wraps the subject in a different interface whereas decorator and proxy wraps the subject in its same interface.